# howto let a function return string from httpclient GetStringAsync(url)

Tags: .net, vb.net, asynchronous, httpclient

```
    Public Shared Async Function Query(url As String) As Task(Of String)
        Dim clnt As New HttpClient
        Dim StringResult As String = Await clnt.GetStringAsync(url)
        Return StringResult
    End Function
```

calling statement goes something like:

```
Function Gettopic(pair As BPair) As topic      
    Dim queryStr As String = String.Format("https://ssss.com/topic", BPairHelper.ToString(pair))

    Return topic.ReadFromJObject(TryCast(JObject.Parse(WebApi.Query(queryStr))
       ("topic"), JObject))       
End Function
```

error: value of type "system.threading.tasks.task(of string) cannot be converted in string.

Goal is make GUI reaction smoother. During web access (timer) Gui is at moments not responsive. 
Using .net 4.5

Answer (score 0):

You must `Await` the method or do `.Result` on it to get the value, otherwise you'll just get the `Task` back, which is what your error is complaining about.

You've designed your `Query` function to be asynchronous, so you can't continue your code because you don't know how long it will take to get the result. Therefore it gives you a `Task(Of String)` back which will eventually give you the result.

If you want it straight away, you can access the `Result` property. This will make your code stop until the Task is completed and returns the String, which is not what you want (this isn't asynchronous).

Since you want to keep your UI thread responsive, you can using `Await` to pause your code but keep the thread processing messages (so your UI is responsive). You'll have to mark your other method as `Async` for this to work.

`Dim theString As String = Await Query(...)`

Answer (score 0):

error: value of type "system.threading.tasks.task(of string) cannot be converted in string.

You are getting this error because the output of the async method is a task. You need to access the result by calling the .Result property on the returned task. In the code snippet shared above JObject.parse expects a string and instead a task is passed.

So you would have to change the above code to as follows: JObject.Parse(WebApi.Query(queryStr).Result).

Regarding the second part where you are indicating that the GUID is not responsive, it could be due to a deadlock because of blocking the UI thread. If you are not careful, you could deadlock your UI. I don't know your specific scenario, but it is good to check the below article.

There is a good article by Stephen Toub which explains this in detail - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115163.aspx

Comment: Yes, the .result results in blocking the gui totally. I dont have the skills/capacity to rewrite the calling statement and make that async.